# I'm having a hard time figuring this code of mine on calculating an hourly employees for his weekly pay

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    const int a = 1200;
    int b = 40;
    int c = 250;
    int hour;

    printf("Enter total hours\n");
    scanf("%d", &hour);

    switch(hour){
        case 1:
            if(hour==40)
                printf("Your week pay is:%d.\n",a);
            break;

        case 2:
            if(hour>40)
                printf("Your week pay is: %d.\n", (hour-40)*b);
            break;

        case 3:
            if(hour>55)
                printf("Your week pay is: %d.\n", a+((hour-40)*b)+c);
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm computing for weekly salary for an hourly employee, the employee have a regular hourly rate of $30 and have an overtime rate of $40. The first 40 hours are paid using regular rate and the succeeding hours are paid using the overtime rate. There is also the hazard pay which when the employee works more than 55 hours their is additional $250.

Comment: You forgot to add the base pay, a,  in the second case.
But what is exactly that you have a hard time figuring out? Can you provide more detail?

Comment: There's no reason to use a `switch` here, just `if/else if/else`. You might think about what should happen if someone works 39 hours of less as well.

Comment: Another way would be to calculate the number of regular hours, the number of overtime hours, and the number of hazard hours. Then compute the pay with a single calulation and a single print statement. Using the very similar `printf` statement three times is high maintenance code bloat.

Comment: `case 1: if(hour==40)` If you end up in `case 1` the value of `hour` must be `1`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a switch statement.
Your code will never show any output.
You can use `if/else` `if/else if/else`. So, remove the switch statement and Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    const int a = 1200;
    int b = 40;
    int c = 250;
    int hour;
    
    printf("Enter total hours\n");
    scanf("%d", &hour);
    
    if(hour > 55)
        printf("Your week pay is: %d.\n", a + ((hour-40)*b)+c);
    else if(hour > 40 )
        printf("Your week pay is: %d.\n", a + (hour-40)*b);
    else
        printf("Your week pay is:%d.\n", a);
    
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Generally, code-only answers without any explanatory text are discouraged at StackOverflow. You could try to explain why you changed code the way you did.

Comment: You may want to change the formulas calculating the pay, too. I'm don't think they are a correct implementation of the problem statement. Also, consider introducing a separate function to calculate the pay, given the hours and then use *one* statement to print the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

### Math?

This is [what the programme is attempting to do](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Piecewise%5B%7B%7B1200%2C+x%3C40%7D%2C+%7B%28x-40%29*40%2C+40%3C%3Dx%3C55%7D%2C+%7B1200%2B%28%28x-40%29*40%29%2B250%2C+55%3C%3Dx%7D%7D%5D); it will not work, anyways, because it is incorrect in it's given form. We are given a stepwise-rate linear function. Given `y`, the payment amount, and `x`, the hours worked, It should:

- intersect the origin;
- be composed of straight lines; [C2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness#Differentiability_classes) should be 0 everywhere it's differentiable;
- have a kink upwards at 40h;
- have a discontinuity at 55h;
- be strictly monotonic, (one would hope at least minimum wage.)

From the problem, the cases are: 0h <= x <= 40h, 40h < x <= 55h, 55h < x. Apparent corner cases are 0h, 40h, and 55h, at least, that one should figure out on paper beforehand to test this programme, (I'd throw in 41h, 56h, and 60h.) Doing a quick sketch of the graph on paper will probably be helpful.

### Putting it into a programme

A `switch` statement is inappropriate because that's testing equality; this is a range of values, so this will be better suited to be a series of `if` blocks. Since the values are monotonically increasing, one could build up the pay,

```
pay = 0
if 55 < x
    pay += bonus
if 40 < x
    pay += ...
    x = 40
...
```

Or, as you have noticed, the section of 40h pay is a constant over 40h, one can separate the cases using the integral, `$30/h * 40h = $1200`, and calculate it directly using a shifted `x`.

```
if 55 < x
    pay = bonus + ...
else if 40 < x
    pay = 1200 + ...
else
    pay = ...
```